# ssl 'module' object has no attribute 'SSLContext'

Tags: python

```
In [1]: import ssl

In [2]: context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

AttributeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-13c9bad66150> in <module>()
----> 1 context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSLContext'
```

Python version:  2.7.6

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`SSLContext` was introduced in 2.7.9, you're using an old version of Python so it doesn't have this attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !  Is there any workaround for python 2.7.6 ?

Comment: Nope, install the latest version.

Comment: I actually tried in python 2.7.10 and still got the AtributeError. Updating to 2.7.11 solved it, I'm still not sure why, but this might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below for Python 2.7.9:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE
```

Comment: Plz remove ";" and press enter key.  Sorry had to add ";" at the end of line because SO was generating error that code can only be posted by selecting code block and inserting 4 spaces. But on mobile there isn't any option available or displaying code block.

Comment: 2.7.6 does not have `create_default_context`